# Charge density on a capacitor plate

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance, classical-electrodynamics

Is charge uniformly distributed on a capacitor plate? For a conductor, charge density is more at sharp ends. So, shouldn't charge density be more on the corners of the plate?

Comment: Sure, there are fringing effects at the edges : http://www.drjamesnagel.com/EM_Beauty.htm

Comment: Well, fringing effects would be there even if the charge was uniform.